# UserForm ListBox Problems

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a userform that the 'RightToLeft' property is True.
I have created a listbox that the 'TextAlign' property is '3 - fmTextAlignRight'.
The listbox contains two columns and rows with a text that longer than the listbox size, so I have setted the 'ColumnWidths' property to see all the text.

I have two problems:

1. When the userform is opened I see the end of the second column instead of the first column.

[image: First Problem]

2. I have a SpinButton, which swap between rows.
   When I have rows more than listbox height, when I swap between rows in the limit, I see two rows with the same values.

[image: Second Problem]

My VBA code of the spin button:

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()
    Call SwapBetweenTwoLines(False, ListBox1)
End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
    Call SwapBetweenTwoLines(True, ListBox1)
End Sub

Sub SwapBetweenTwoLines(up As Boolean, listbox)
    Dim index As Integer, new_index As Integer
    index = listbox.ListIndex
    If (((up = True) And (index > 0)) Or _
        ((up = False) And (index < listbox.ListCount - 1))) Then
        If (up = True) Then
            new_index = index - 1
        Else
            new_index = index + 1
        End If

        Dim key As String, value As String
        key = listbox.Column(0, index)
        value = listbox.Column(1, index)
        listbox.Column(0, index) = listbox.Column(0, new_index)
        listbox.Column(1, index) = listbox.Column(1, new_index)
        listbox.Column(0, new_index) = key
        listbox.Column(1, new_index) = value
        listbox.Selected(new_index) = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help...

Comment: +1 for articulating your answer with some images and details.

Comment: If you keep default alignment, or Left to Right, does it work alright?

Comment: @Benjy For the swapping, can you please also provide us your VBA code for the Spinner buttons?

Comment: I have uploaded the excel file to SkyDrive. [Example.xls](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=94dfef96bbfb9231&page=view&resid=94DFEF96BBFB9231!150&parid=94DFEF96BBFB9231!117&authkey=!&Bpub=SDX.SkyDrive&Bsrc=Share) [Example.xlsm](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=94dfef96bbfb9231&page=view&resid=94DFEF96BBFB9231!152&parid=94DFEF96BBFB9231!117&authkey=!&Bpub=SDX.SkyDrive&Bsrc=Share) Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have succeeded to resolve the second problem.

I just should write the last command (listbox.Selected(new_index) = True) before the values inserting, not after.

Does anyone have a solution to the first problem?

Thanks...